# Firebase cloud messaging - Vantagens

Tags: android, firebase

Além de ter a possibilidade de trabalhar com messages, no estilo push notifications;

Que vantagens vocês veem no FCM?

Falo de recursos que realmente são importante e ajudam os desenvolvedores, e não simplesmente as N features do FCM.

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase Cloud Messaging**

[O Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br) é uma solução de mensagens entre plataformas que permite a entrega confiável de mensagens e notificações sem custo. Com ele, você pode notificar um aplicativo do cliente que novos e-mails ou outros dados estão disponíveis para sincronização.

**Vantagem**

A vantagem do [FCM](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/05/firebase-expands-to-become-unified-app-platform.html) é estar disponível gratuitamente e para uso ilimitado,  suportar mensagens em iOS, Android e na web, e ser altamente otimizado para confiabilidade e bateria de eficiência. Ele é construído para escala e já envia 170 bilhões de mensagens por dia para dois bilhões de dispositivos.

Principais funções, segundo a [documentação](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/05/firebase-expands-to-become-unified-app-platform.html):

> - Direcionamento versátil de mensagens: Distribua mensagens a seu aplicativo cliente de três maneiras - para dispositivos únicos, para
>     grupos de dispositivos ou para dispositivos inscritos em tópicos.
> - Suporte a mensagens de dados e notificações: Entregue notificações de até 2 KB, cargas úteis de dados de até 4 KB e envie mensagens com
>     carga útil de notificação e dados.
> - Mensagens ascendentes de aplicativos cliente: Envie mensagens de confirmação, bate-papo e outras mensagens dos dispositivos de volta ao
>     servidor por meio de um canal de conexão confiável e com pouco consumo
>     de bateria do FCM.

**Como funciona?**

Uma implementação do FCM inclui um servidor de aplicativos no seu ambiente, que interage com o FCM usando o protocolo `HTTP` ou `XMPP`, e um aplicativo cliente. Além disso, o FCM inclui o console do Notificações, que pode ser usado para enviar notificações a aplicativos cliente.

O Firebase Notifications foi criado com base no Firebase Cloud Messaging e compartilha o mesmo SDK de FCM SDK para desenvolvimento de clientes. Para testar ou enviar mensagens de marketing ou interação com direcionamento e análises avançadas, você pode usar o Notifications. Para implementações com requisitos de mensagens mais complexos, o FCM é a escolha certa.

[image: Diagrama da arquitetura do Firebase Cloud Messaging]

Answer (score 0):

O Firebase Cloud é um backend as a service que possuí diversas Features, ou seja, a ideia é que utilizando-o, você não precise de uma linguagem rodando no servidor.

Como funcionaria ?

Para grande parte das aplicações Mobile, não é necessário grande regras de negócio, ou uma backend tão robusta, normalmente tudo o que ele precisa é um banco para guardar as informações e uma API para recuperar essas informações.

Nesse caso, você só iria inserir informações no Firebird, e ser notificado quando essas informações mudarem, permitindo inclusive espelhar com um banco no próprio aplicativo.